# Facebook application: redirecting

Tags: facebook

I'm developing an application on Facebook (in Italian).
The `index.php` file is this:

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');

 require_once 'connessione.php';
 require_once 'appinclude.php';
 require_once 'home.php';
?>
```

In a page of the application, there is the button `'Home'`, which is written as thus:

```
<a href="index.php">HOME</a>
```

When I try to click on the button an error message appears:

> The URL you entered is not permitted by the application
>   configuration.: One or more of the URLs entered are not permitted by
>   the settings of the application. The URL must match that of the
>   Website or the main page of the application and the domain must be a
>   subdomain of one of the domains.

I've tried multiple things:

```
<a href="http://<..my_site..>"HOME</a>
<a href="https://<..my_site..>"HOME</a>
<a href="home.php>"HOME</a>
```

but I failed. How do I proceed in order to get a correct redirecting button.

Comment: OK, I solved it: in my 'appinclude.php' file, there was an error in canvas URL setting, i wrote a wrong address.

Answer (score 0):

All these URLs need to be under your website domain that you have written in your facebook application. You therefore need to change the website URL in the facebook application to the URL where all the pages in question are hosted, for example:

Your webpage is: `http://www.mynewpage.com`

Then all your redirect pages should be under this domain, like this:

`http://www.mynewpage.com/directory/otherwebpages`

Mention your domain name in the facebook application under `Settings->Website URL`

Comment: newguy, thanks for the repeat speed  :) I really don't know where to change my URL settings; my application is in "Develop mode"

Comment: Just goto the developer tab on Facebook-> Click on your App-> goto Settings tab and then change the Website URL mentioned in it.

Comment: field 'Main page URL' already fixed;  field 'Secure Canvas URL' () already fixed; field App Domains now fixed (i've fixed now for the first time) the same address of the other fields...but the problem is not solved  :(

Comment: App Domains: <..mysite..>.ssl.altervista.org    -   Main page URL: http://<..mysite..>.altervista.org/    -    Secure Canvas URL:  https://<..mysite..>.ssl.altervista.org/    Where am I going wrong?